# Is there any example of a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose interior is empty with infinite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

**Question:** Is there any example of a  closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose interior is empty with infinite measure?

Comment: A line and a plane have finite measures. Their measures are zero.

Comment: Ohh.. Yes.. right..

Comment: Are you familiar with the existence of closed sets of reals with empty interior and *positive* measure? If so, you can use that here ...

Comment: Yes... I think Fat Cantor Set.. It is closed and nowhere dense and have positive measure..

Comment: The fat Cantor set lives inside $[0,1]$, right?  So translate copies of it into $[1,2], [2,3]. \dots$.

Comment: Yes.. I got it.. Thanks❤